# setjmp.h in kernel space?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

Is `setjmp` and `longjmp` available in kernel space?
I want to jump between functions.

Is it possible to run gclib headers from kernel modules?
If yes, then how to use them in kernel modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding glibc, the answer is no.
When programming in kernel space standard c library is not available, however, the kernel itself implements some of the functionality of libc.
You can find relevant headers under linux/include.

Regarding setjmp, I don't remember, but you can use lxr(linux cross reference) to search for it

Comment: setjmp and longjmp are also POSIX c library calls, e.g. from glibc and as such not availavble in the kernel. Kernel programming differs quite a bit from userspace c-programming.

Comment: @thuovila:Which kernel function will replicate the functionality of setjmp and longjmp? Any ideas?

Comment: @RaunakMukhia Sorry, I dont know. Perhaps you can find some pointers at [kernelnewbies.org/KernelHacking](http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelHacking)